# Probability of selecting two disks of identical color is equal to selecting two disks of different color

Tags: probability

I have encountered a probability question which deeply confuses me. It goes,

There are 25 disks, which are either black or white. If the probability of simultaneously selecting two disks of the same color is equal to the probability of selecting two disks of different color, how many black disks are there?

This means that P(Same color) and P(Different colors) are both equal to 0.5.

So I tried, (x/25)*((25-x)/24)=0.5, in attempt to model the probability of selecting different colored disks. This doesn't work for some reason- the quadratic equation has no solutions. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct, since two different and 2 the same are mutually exclusive and include all possible outcomes, so p + p = 1 ,I can't solve my quadratic either though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think of drawing the two disks simultaneously (combinations) the probability of getting different colors is
$$\frac{x(25-x)}{\binom{25}2}.$$

If you think of drawing them one at a time (permutations) the same probability is
$$\frac x{25}\cdot\frac{25-x}{24}+\frac{25-x}{25}\cdot\frac x{24}.$$

These two expressions are equivalent. The probability is $\frac12$ when you have

> $15$ of one color and $10$ of the other.

Your mistake was that your expression for drawing disks of different colors is actually (if we call $x$ the number of black disks) the probability of drawing first a black disk and then a white disk; this is just half of the probability you want, because you overlook the probability of drawing the white disk first.